# dpkg python dependency

Tags: python, dpkg, dependencies

Attempt to install a [weather app](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/09/22/install-simple-weather-indicator-ubuntu-16-04/) resulted in a dependency issue:

```
myhost:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i indicator-weather_0.9-0ubuntu4_all.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package indicator-weather.
(Reading database ... 214200 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack indicator-weather_0.9-0ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Unpacking indicator-weather (0.9-0ubuntu4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of indicator-weather:
 indicator-weather depends on python-gtk2; however:
  Package python-gtk2 is not installed.
 indicator-weather depends on python-gi; however:
  Package python-gi is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package indicator-weather (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 indicator-weather
```

1. Is there a command / technique to automagically resolve dependency
   issues at install time?
2. Is there a clever command to automagically resolve commands post install?
3. Is the simplest resolution to install pyton-gtk2 and gi, then rerun the install command?

Thank you for providing a command line example.

Comment: Automatic dependency handling is apt's job, not dpkg. Apt will download and queue the dependencies for dpkg to install in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Install a package and get dependencies from repositories with

```
sudo gdebi package.deb
```

If you already installed the package with missed dependencies, you can dowload and install dependencies automatically with

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Also available is a graphical version `gdebi-gtk`, linked to `.deb` nautilus right click action "Open With GDebi Package Installer".